# React Router - different header for Private and Public routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to organise my routes in such a way that all public routes will have a public header component and the private routes will have private header component.

With my current approach the `HeaderContainer` is visible on all routes, and I want to split it in two `PublicHeaderContainer` and `PrivateHeaderContainer`.

My App.js looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <div>

            <Grid centered>
              <Grid.Column computer={12} mobile={15} tablet={12}>
                <HeaderContainer/>

                <Segment>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path="/welcome" component={LandingPage}/>
                    <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={BodyComponent}/>
                    <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp}/>
                    <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn}/>
                    <Route path="/#/:itemId" component={ItemView}/>

                    {/*order matters this should be the last route*/}
                    <Route path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
                  </Switch>
                </Segment>
              </Grid.Column>
            </Grid>

            <FooterContainer/>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The `PrivateRoute` is defined like this:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
  <Route {...rest} render={props => {

    //if (!isUserLogged()) {
    if (false) {
      // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
      return <Redirect to={{pathname: '/sign-in', state: {from: props.location}}}/>
    }

    // authorised so return component
    return <Component {...props} />
  }}/>
)
```

I tried wrapping the `<Component {...props} />` in the `PrivateRoute` around a Grid and add the `PrivateHeaderContainer` but this breaks my app and when I try to access private route the application just hangs, no errors in the terminal just hangs ...

I'm not sure what's the general approach how do people organise their components to make that work?

My question is asking about the Header component, but I might as well have different Footer for Private/Public routes as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Couldn't you effectively use the same logic for your Private Routes to determine what Header to show.

Have a component that will either render the public `HeaderContainer` or the private `PrivateHeaderContainer`.

### Header.js

```
const Header = () => (
    if (isUserLogged()) {
       return <PrivateHeaderContainer/>
    } else {
      // not logged in so display public
      return <HeaderContainer/>
    }
  }}/>
)
export default Header
```

### App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Router>
          <div>
        <Grid centered>
          <Grid.Column computer={12} mobile={15} tablet={12}>
            <Header/>
            <Segment>
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/welcome" component={LandingPage}/>
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={BodyComponent}/>
                <Route path="/sign-up" component={SignUp}/>
                <Route path="/sign-in" component={SignIn}/>
                <Route path="/#/:itemId" component={ItemView}/>

                {/*order matters this should be the last route*/}
                <Route path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
              </Switch>
            </Segment>
          </Grid.Column>
        </Grid>

        <FooterContainer/>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Fragment>
);
```

Comment: I got you previous answer working, this one is even better!

Comment: Oh forreal? Haha I honestly didn't think the earlier one would work but this one is much simpler. @AntonBelev